# CreateMeasurementGraphics issue

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, gdi+

On a specific web server I'm taking the default printer and using it to create a device context for printing; I'm facing the following issue using `CreateMeasurementGraphics`.

Using this code (VB .NET sorry :-( ):

```
Dim ps As PageSettings = GetPageSettings(parms)
Dim pr As PrinterSettings = GetPrinterSettings()
printerGraphics = pr.CreateMeasurementGraphics(ps)
```

I'm getting:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Eccezione generata dalla
>   destinazione di una chiamata. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException:
>   Memoria insufficiente.    in
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)    in
>   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics(PageSettings
>   pageSettings)    in
>   Sistemi.Builder.Tools.Printing.EmfDC.OnPageChanged(PrintPageParms
>   parms)

(translated is OutOfMemory)

What I have checked:

- System.Drawing objects are correctly disposed so I'm not reaching the 10000 limit
- the application is running in full trust
- the IIS user have permissions

I'm going crazy...

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview/

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant I'll go deep on it; it happens only on one web server, I can't reproduce it anywhere

Comment: @HansPassant finally solved! See the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved; it's a known issue caused by a combination of 64bit server-enable 32bit on the application pool-impersonation.

To solve the issue it must be removed the enable 32bit flag on the application pool.

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/05/19/printing-successfully-using-impersonation-from-a-32-bit-application-on-a-64-bit-system/